# selenium does not open URL in chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm quiet new to selenium and my selenium will only open the chrome browser but not the URL. My code is very simple.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('my-path-to-chrome')
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")`
```

I looked at console and found found 4 errors:

```
SW registered
chrome-search://thumb/https://adwords.google.com/mcm/Mcm?authuser=0&__u=4760590279&__c=3865711759#c&app=mcm Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
screener.ashx Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
thumb/ Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
thumb/ Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Chrome version: Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Python: 3.6
Selenium: 3.9

Thank you!

Edit- I solved it, for those of you looking here are the steps.

1) First download chrome driver, just google it
2) change the driver path from your chrome to the chrome driver
It's good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also dealing with the same issue and got resolves using the below steps:

1. download the latest [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and keep it inside the project directory.
2. set the chromedriver path during the driver initialization.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I have already resolved the issue as stated in my post. And Jdk do not apply to issue as this is a python code problem instead of Java problem.

Comment: You have done a question and replied together with it in the same post. Is it right rule. Why have you done this? You should delete this.

Comment: I edited my original post because I thought I would help other who are googling, but you answered a question with java help is just ignorant.

Comment: This is Q&A site. How would you help others giving the answer in the post. There is a place to give the answer or vote up the answer if other's answer is right. I already updated my answer.